# Paypal Adaptive Payments PHP Soap SDK Undefined Definitions

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to integrate an adaptive payments system to my codeigniter project on my centos server. SOAP is installed on my server (I executed "yum install php-soap" via ssh and restarted the server already), and I'm getting errors like this when I try to run:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT - assumed 'XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT'
Filename: SOAPEncoder/SOAPEncoder.php
Line Number: 41
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Use of undefined constant XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT - assumed 'XML_SERIALIZER_OPTION_INDENT'
Filename: SOAPEncoder/SOAPEncoder.php
Line Number: 41
```

What am I missing, how can I solve this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to install the XML_Serializer PEAR package: http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer/

```
pear install XML_Serializer
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been sick... Yup, this was the exact problem, thanks!